# Getting a grid to wrap in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid I created wrap properly for mobile accessibility but the grid won't wrap around when the window size is small enough.

I've been trying to use `auto-fill` and `auto-fit` to make it wrap which does work but the buttons don't automatically space themselves out to fit the entire page at bigger window sizes. Is there any way to make the buttons wrap around when the page is smaller but still automatically space the right. Problems I had with using auto fill and fit also required all of the buttons to be the same size or else the buttons wouldn't be evenly spaced.

Code below is the version I have right now that uses auto for the grid spacing.

```css
.bttns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #4A3E94;
  background-color: #d19dfc;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
}

.b1 {
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    background-color: #4A3E94;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #4A3E94;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.b2 {
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    background-color: #4A3E94;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #4A3E94;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.b3 {
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    background-color: #4A3E94;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #4A3E94;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.b4 {
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    background-color: #4A3E94;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #4A3E94;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.b5 {
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    background-color: #4A3E94;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #4A3E94;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bttns">
  <div class="b1">
    <a href="Imagess/pholdr.png" target="_blank">Art</a>
  </div>

  <div class="b2">
    <a href="Imagess/pholdr.png" target="_blank">Blog</a>
  </div>

  <div class="b3">
    <a href="/About/abt.html" target="_self">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="b4">
    <a href="Imagess/steviekitty.png" target="_blank">Music</a>
  </div>

  <div class="b5">
    <a href="Imagess/kittr.png" target="_blank">WIP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid seems like overkill here. Flexbox would handle it nicely with simpler rules. Here I've aligned flex content to center so things don't spread out awkwardly on large screens. You could use `justify-content: space-around`, for example, if that's what you want.

FYI, you're using classes incorrectly. Unless there's something else in your plans, you should use *one* class for your menu items, not one for each. That much repetition in your CSS is a big red flag.

```css
.bttns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #4A3E94;
  background-color: #d19dfc;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
}

.menu-btn {
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    background-color: #4A3E94;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #4A3E94;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bttns">
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <a href="Imagess/pholdr.png" target="_blank">Art</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">
    <a href="Imagess/pholdr.png" target="_blank">Blog</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">
    <a href="/About/abt.html" target="_self">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">
    <a href="Imagess/steviekitty.png" target="_blank">Music</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">
    <a href="Imagess/kittr.png" target="_blank">WIP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```